# @OneToOne with @Id: Composite-id class must implement Serializable

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have two simple entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK")
    User user;
}
```

When I run my Spring Boot application I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: Address
```

But the entities are almost identical to those in [JPA Spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#examples-of-derived-identities) (Section 2.4.1, Example 4). For some reason Hibernate thinks that the `user` attribute is a composite id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the example, the `Dependent` is tagged with `@IdClass(DependentId.class)`. Maybe try adding `@IdClass(User.class)` to your `Address` class

Comment: I'm talking about the 4th example, ```@Entity public class MedicalHistory```, it's not annotated with ```@IdClass```

Comment: Does it work with a PK of type `String` on `User`?

Comment: Nope, it does not

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK")
    User user;
}
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) of hibernate documentation.

Comment: Yes, that's how I have it now. But the question is why JPA Spec example gives me an error. Is it possible that Hibernate doesn't support this kind of `@Id`?

Comment: Hibernate 5.4 supports jpa 2.2 (See [this](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/)), your link refers to the jpa 3.0

Comment: What about [this](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)? JPA 2.1

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using @Id two times in one Entity class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).